# set an image background on a scrolling activity

Tags: android, scroll, background

I'd like to change the background of a standard-generated `ScrollingActivity` (to an image).
 Changing the background of the `content_scrolling.xml`  affects the area where I can put items in only.

Is there a simple way I missed?
*(I am pretty surprised that I was not able to find an answer, so here we go)*

[the blue background should be replaced by an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdRk4.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change the background attribute of android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:background="@drawable/backgraound">
```

or change the background attribute of android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:background="@drawable/backgraound">
```

Comment: The view that Android Studio auto-generates is a `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`, so do I have to replace that?

Comment: @Nicolai Androids Studio auto-generates 2 layouts layout/activity_scrolling.xml and layout/content_scrolling.xml, you will fine the CollapsingToolbarLayout in activity_scrolling.xml one, you can add the background to CollapsingToolbarLayout or AppBarLayout, try both see which one works for you

Comment: I got it to work by adding the `background` attribute to the `AppBarLayout` (did not test the alternative yet) - Thank you very much!

Comment: Just tried the alternative - works fine as well, I didn't notice a difference.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED AT THE END

Why don´t you create a normal Activity (`LinearLayout`) with its background and then a `ScrollView` inside it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/your_image"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        ...">
            Your ScrollView content
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

EDIT:

Maybe you can take a look on this [lgvalle/Material-Animations](https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations) library.

Comment: I'd like to have this cool transition and the FAB (see picture)
I wouldn't be able to achieve this with a regular ScrollView, would I?

Comment: I´ve edited my first answer with a link that maybe can help you.

Comment: Seems pretty interesting, but I don't understand how it could help me setting a background (or what do you mean?)

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is a "FrameLayout". It works like a Stack, or a layer layout. Each new child can be put in the front of the previous child.

An example:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#99acd347"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Android" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Here you will have an ImageView behind a TextView.

Comment: Okay, but there is no preset for the cool transition of the title into the ActionBar, right?
Thanks anyway :)